# How to get keyword from URl and search in db retrive details in json format + PHP

Tags: php, json

I have an URL like this:

```
www.example.com/?s=test
```

Searching for keyword 'test' value should match the mysql db and retrieve the results as `JSON` format using `PHP`. Please can anybody guide me to achieve this?

Comment: show us what you have done so far.

Comment: select * from table where column_name = $_GET['test']

Comment: i want json format, could you help me, how to write

Comment: you can just use  json_encode($result_array) to  get the json format  result array

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use below query to fetch the records from database and after that convert the results into json format using `json_encode()` function.

To fetch the records from database table.

```
select * from your_table_name where your_column_name = $_GET['test'];
```

Then use `json_encode()` to convert retrieved data into json format.

Answer (score 0):

```
$search_text = $_GET['s'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM your_table_name where your_column_name = '$search_text'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo json_encode($result->fetch_assoc());
```